# How to import image from the google search?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

https://support.google.com/docs/thread/189086003/how-to-import-image-from-the-search-engine?hl=en
I am looking for a function similar to this case.

For example, there is the word car in (A1) sheet, and this is on the xpath address in Google Images (//*[@id="islrg"]/div[1]/div[1]/a[1]/div[1]/ img) I want to display the first image.

Just search Google for car
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PI5hg.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYjNx.jpg)

I hope the image of the first red Lamborghini comes out on the sheet like the one I pressed like this.

I notice google image link form is

google.com/search?q= (searched word) &tbm=isch

for example,If i want to see the first situation(noting clicked yet and image of word),linked should be

google.com/search?q=car&tbm=isch

and xpath link is

//*[@id="islrg"]/div[1]/div[1]/a[1]/div[1]/img

so I made the

=IMAGE(IMPORTXML("https://www.google.com/search?q="&I169&"&tbm=isch","//*[@id='islrg']/div[1 ]/div[1]/a[1]/div[1]/img"), 1)

​but it is not working and what is wrong.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOTI6.png)
​

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, if you want the function, it is quite complicated and memory consuming

if it helps you can use this script

getRange("A1:A5") in this line you change the range you want the script to handle your commands if you need to enter only in A1, then enter A1 there

getRange("B1:B5") here you enter the cells in which the image should be displayed

```js
function searchGoogleImages() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var keywords = sheet.getRange("A1:A5").getValues();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
    var keyword = keywords[i][0];
    
    if (keyword) {
      var searchUrl = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + encodeURIComponent(keyword) + "&tbm=isch";
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(searchUrl);
      var content = response.getContentText();
      var startIndex = content.indexOf('https://encrypted-tbn');
      var endIndex = content.indexOf('&amp;', startIndex);
      var imageUrl = content.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
      
      var formula = '=IMAGE("' + imageUrl + '")';
      var targetCell = sheet.getRange("B1:B5").getCell(i + 1, 1);
      targetCell.setFormula(formula);
    } else {
      var targetCell = sheet.getRange("B1:B5").getCell(i + 1, 1);
      targetCell.clearContent();
    }
  }
}
```

To run this script, follow these steps:

1. Open Google Sheets.
2. Select "Tools" -> "Script Editor".
3. Paste the above code into the script editor.
4. Click "Save".
5. Go to the rules tab (alarm clock icon).
6. Add a trigger.
7. Select the script and check it to refresh after editing.
8. Close the script editor.
9. Enter a keyword in cell A1.
10. The script will fetch the first image from Google search results and place it in cell B1.

I hope I helped.